# Tensorflow - The source code of the tensorflow_inception_graph.pb

Tags: tensorflow

Does anyone know the original source code of the tensorflow_inception_graph.pb.

I really wan't to know the operation in the example project

The tensorflow/example/android  - Read me.
Tensorflow Android Camera Demo

https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/examples/android/
https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip

Thanks

Comment: Where do you get it from?

Comment: I wan't to know the python files which generate the tensorflow_inception_graph.pb which provider from the url in tensorflow  example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code has not yet been released. As the [release announcement for the latest ImageNet model](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/d/msg/discuss/kl3d9DspOMw/YIpdtXerCQAJ) mentions, the team is working on releasing the complete Python training framework for this type of model, including the code for building the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I think you the rb and inception labels assets directly from [here](https://github.com/miyosuda/TensorFlowAndroidDemo/tree/master/app/src/main/assets).